# PHP Include Error w/ CSS

Tags: php, css, include

I have having difficulties on this one page login.php.  Because of the nature of the session, it does not allow a `$page` to be called.  I included the header the same way I did on all other pages.  The code highlighted between the ===== is my header included with `$page` defined for the `< ul >` so I can call a different class each page. But it's not working on the login page due to the `sessionstart`. I can get it to work fine on other pages.

If you have any ideas let me know.

```
<?php
session_start();


if ($_POST['username']) {



if( strtolower($_POST['code'])!= strtolower($_SESSION['texto'])){

function headertop($page) {

    include('header.php');

}

headertop('login');


echo "<br /><br />SECURITY CODE ERROR... "; 




include('footer.php');

exit();
}
```

Comment: What's not working? I don't understand.

Comment: Visit makebux.com and see how every page except "login" highlights the nav when you click.

Comment: I, for one, will not be visiting makebux.com now or ever.

Comment: Do not format code as text. I suggest to edit your message and delete all code and then again copypaste from the actual source code and then select it and then press the `010101` button or `Ctrl+K`.

Comment: NSD than don't!! no one is forcing you to help, your comment is worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, stop validating POST without an isset() function, so it should look something like `if (isset($_POST['key']) :` etc.

Next, i suppose You're defining that function in each file ?

You screwed up the definition of it by defining the include to `include('header.php');` and not the $page. Then why are U sending the $page parameter at all ? You call it then from header.php ? That's some lame code.

Anyway, what you need to do is a switch or many if-else-if-s in your code, based on the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

```
switch ( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) {
default:
case '/index.php':  
    $tab = 'homenav';               
    break;

case '/surf.php':   
    $tab = 'surfnav';               
    break;

case '/register.php':   
    $tab = 'registernav';                   
    break;
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if I take header.php out of the include than it wont print my header. The function is what is suppose to call the $page and each page is defined in the CSS

Comment: It's lame to call variables you define in this file from header.php, not a really good practice, and I personally haven't seen a code like yours in years.

What you need is to define some rules in something like config.php, based on $_SERVER variables, not some $page variable based on cookie value. Look at my code, I'll edit it in few seconds.

Comment: I tried adding that to config and didnt work. What would I be doing wrong to the current code?